# PCB Mount Push Button Identification Help

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, components, identification

Can anyone help me identify the push button on this PCB board taken from a router? The button is circled in RED and is the one on the backside of the router, used to turn it on/off.

I would like to use it in my circuit but don't know what it is called.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pushbutton switch right-angle, through hole. You probably want alternating on/off action for an on/off switch unless it's a soft switch that just signals a micro or whatever to do the on/off function.

For example, [this](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/E-Switch%20PDFs/P227EE1CXC_Dwg.pdf) type:

[image]

A parametric search at any distributor should show you lots of options. You may or may not have to order the operator separately.

Comment: Got it .. thanks ! .. for some reason push button did not come to my mind .. got hung up on 90 degrees